# FCKeditor. Work with image

Tags: asp.net, javascript, image, crash, fckeditor

I have two problems with image upload in FCKeditor.

I.
The folder for uploaded files is "user" and it situated in the root of the web-site.
There are two ways to upload image in FCKeditor:
1. Insert/Edit Image - Browse Server - Upload a new file in this folder - Upload. Image is uploaded to the folder "Image", which situated in the folder "user".
2. Insert/Edit Image - Tab "Upload" - Upload - Send it to the server. Image is uploaded to the folder "user" and I can not see it, using Browse Server, because Browse Server shows folder "Image" (and other subfolders of "user"), not "user". 
How can I change it? I want to have access to images, which was uploaded using Tab Upload in the Browse Server, too. May be, I have some errors in configuration?
I use ASP .NET connector, windows hosting (IIS 6.0).
The configbration in config.ascx is following:

```
    string ex= Request.ApplicationPath;
    if (ex == "/") ex = "";
    // URL path to user files.
    //UserFilesPath = ex+"/user/";
    UserFilesPath = ex + "/";
```

II.
When I use FCKedtor in the local computer, everything works fine. But when I upload image to the remote server using Tab "Upload", the component is hanging. Image  really is uploaded to the folder, but FCKeditor hangs every time. 
Insert/Edit Image - Browse Server works fine in the remote server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the second problem. You have to [patch the FCKEditor](http://dev.ckeditor.com/attachment/ticket/2115/2115_4.patch#L38).